# mysql query to add a character 's' to each row in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a table called 'parts' for example i have different car parts in each row like Brake Cylinder,Brake Light Switch,bumper,Bonnet etc i want a mysql query to add 's' at the end of each part name in the table for eg:'Bonnets'

Comment: Doing that will result in stuff like butterflys, boxs,  gooses, etc.

Comment: It will also result in: Brake Light Switchs when it should be Brake Light Switches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) in an `UPDATE` statement::

```
UPDATE `parts`
SET `name` = CONCAT(`name`, 's');
```

Alternatively, to skip rows that already end with an `s`:

```
UPDATE `parts`
SET `name` = CONCAT(`name`, 's')
WHERE `name` NOT LIKE '%s';
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use string concatenation

Here is a MySQL example:

```
Update [table_name] set [column_name] = concat([column_name], 's');
```